# Where to find Firebase usage report?

Tags: firebase

The legacy Firebase Dashboard included an *Analytics* tab that reported *Data Stored*, *Database Bandwidth*, and *Peak Concurrents*. Where can I find these reports in the new May 2016 version of Firebase?

I would like to be able to track bandwidth and storage usage for my applications.

Comment: The support response in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37403767/where-to-find-concurrent-connections-bandwidth-etc-in-new-firebase-dashboard-a) indcates that they're working on it.